# Sufficient conditions for Hamilton paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

I have a conjecture about the Hamiltonian path, expressed as follows. Is it correct?

> For a connected graph $G$, if every vertex of $G$ is an end-vertex of some longest path of $G$, then $G$ has a Hamilton path.

Comment: This should be a very hard problem, because it's very similar to Lovász conjecture. Every vertex of a finite connected vertex-transitive graph $G$, is an end-vertex of some longest path of $G$.